# Sum the array values

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I'm developing a ranking table that contains names and scores columns. There is also a extra column available only to display the Total, which is the sum of all the scores.

I'm using the `array_sum` and pulling information from the `$scores` array where the values are organized. Even though the sum is working correctly, it only returns me the value for the name specified in the square brackets. Ie: `array_sum($scores["Mike"])` prints 37 for every row in the loop). On the other hand, if I only use `array_sum($scores)` it prints 0 for every row in the loop! I need the correctly sum for each name into the array.

Here is what I have:

```
//scores values for each name
$scores = array(
    "Mike"    => array(04, 03, 00, 07, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 04),
    "Kyle"    => array(07, 01, 00, 03, 04, 01, 00, 07, 03, 04, 04),
    "Johnny"  => array(07, 07, 00, 03, 00, 04, 00, 01, 01, 04, 03),
    "Will"    => array(03, 04, 00, 03, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 04),
    "Vasques" => array(03, 01, 00, 03, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 07)
);

//start loop for rows
foreach($scores as $key=>$value) {
  echo "<tr>";
  //column for the names
  echo "<td>$key</td>";
  //Total Column
  echo "<td class='total' align='center' valign='middle'>" . array_sum($scores["Mike"]) . "</td>";
  //loop for columns where the score should be displayed
  for($x=0; $x<count($value); $x++) {
    echo "<td class='games tip' align='center' valign='middle'>".sprintf('%02d', $value[$x])."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

It should display something like this:

```
Mike    37   04  03  00  07  04  07  00  01  00  07  04
Kyle    34   07  01  00  03  04  01  00  07  03  04  04
Johnny  33   03  01  00  03  04  07  00  01  00  07  07
```

and so on... the 37, 34 and 33 are the sums.

Comment: `array_sum($scores["Mike"])` should be `array_sum($value)` - Also, be warned that your leading 0 tells PHP that the number is octal, 00 to 07 are the same, but 08 and 09 is invalid, while 010 is the same as the decimal number 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
echo "<td class='total' align='center' valign='middle'>" . array_sum($value) . "</td>";
```

You need to sum your `$value` var, not the `Mike` key.

As OP have questioned, this can be used to order the array.
Add this before your foreach loop.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return array_sum($b) - array_sum($a);
}
uasort($scores, "cmp");
```

Comment: Silly me! Of course it should be the `$value`!!!! I should learn stop appealing the Stack Overflow every time when I'm desperate! hahaha Thank you! I have an extra question! Is that possible to sort from highest value to the lowest??

Comment: instead of immediately displaying the values via html, pull the calculated values into an array, then use array_sort() http://www.php.net//manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Thank you! That was almost there! The sort worked pretty fine, however, the name columns has been substituted by number from 0 up to 4. Why did the names got off the list??

Comment: @CaioFerrari hmm, my bad, try using `uasort` instead of `usort`

Comment: I tried `uasort` and worked pretty fine! Well done! That works great! However, there is something weird. I notice that when I add numbers 8 and 9 in the array, it gets converted to 0 and, moreover, it subtracts some points! Weird! But it does not affect me, because the maximum points we can get in the score are 7! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @CaioFerrari see scragar comment in your answer. It's because the front 0 in your numbers, php will see it as octal, not decimal

Answer (score 0):

try to change `array_sum($scores["Mike"])` to `array_sum($scores[$key])` and add a `<table></table>` tag

```
$scores = array(
    "Mike"    => array(04, 03, 00, 07, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 04),
    "Kyle"    => array(07, 01, 00, 03, 04, 01, 00, 07, 03, 04, 04),
    "Johnny"  => array(07, 07, 00, 03, 00, 04, 00, 01, 01, 04, 03),
    "Will"    => array(03, 04, 00, 03, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 04),
    "Vasques" => array(03, 01, 00, 03, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 07)
);
echo '<table>';
//start loop for rows
foreach($scores as $key=>$value) {
  echo "<tr>";
  //column for the names
  echo "<td>$key</td>";
  //Total Column
  echo "<td class='total' align='center' valign='middle'>" . array_sum($scores[$key]) . "</td>";
  //loop for columns where the score should be displayed
  for($x=0; $x<count($value); $x++) {
    echo "<td class='games tip' align='center' valign='middle'>".sprintf('%02d', $value[$x])."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

output:-

```
Mike    37  04  03  00  07  04  07  00  01  00  07  04
Kyle    34  07  01  00  03  04  01  00  07  03  04  04
Johnny  30  07  07  00  03  00  04  00  01  01  04  03
Will    33  03  04  00  03  04  07  00  01  00  07  04
Vasques 33  03  01  00  03  04  07  00  01  00  07  07
```

Comment: Almost that! I got that `array_sum($value)` should be the correct way! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

sorting multi-dimensional array you can use "array_multisort" with SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC constant in parameters